# only 1.000 results in google webmaster tools 404 not found

Tags: google-search-console, error, vbulletin

One great problem: I have a customer with a magazine in Wordpress and a forum with vbulletin. In this days google webmaster tools show over 175.000 url not founded (this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1NKM8MZ68y5dE82b2RzUXAwS2c/view?usp=sharing) for the screenshot). One Last thing: google webmaster tools show only the first 1.000 results and in any other way last others.

Another big problem is the strange url (look this [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1NKM8MZ68y5M0p2WUI4cEZIS1E/view?usp=sharing)). I'm waiting for any kind of suggest.

Thank you

Comment: I am a bit confused. Are the 404 links for pages that should exist or do not and should not exist? As well, does it appear that the cause may be links from another site such as your second image? Could it be a negative SEO attack?? This number of 404's being that you did not make them, should not hurt you. But if there is a problem with your site, I would be concerned. Can you check the log files to see if there is a referrer for these 404's? Any additional information you can provide will help us understand how to answer the question.

Comment: the links doesn't exist: many of them are generated by the forum and in all this I can't see all the links but rather only  1000 on 175.000 links are visible on google webmaster tools.

Comment: I am not sure how the links are made. I do know these products enough to guide you. If your forum is making these links, I would be focusing on removing the broken links as fast as I can. For a short period, you can make your 404 error a landing page or some other page. As for GWT, I would not worry about the list- you do not have to clear them. You can just let them site there till they drop- that is fine. Just focus on repairing the link situation and short-circuiting the 404 with a soft-404 temporarily till fixed.

Comment: but why i can show only 1.000 links of 175.000?

Comment: That is just a Google thing. Not sure why. They limit most if not all lists to 1000 per day. If you can fix the problem, then you will be able to *Mark as Fixed* these 404s to remove 1000 per day. But I would only do that if you really need to see them. You can use http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/ to find the broken links. It does require a license for more than 500 pages, but it is affordable and excellent! Most people opt for this tool to help keep their site healthy. It can help you identify exactly where these broken links are. You should be able to see a pattern this way.

Answer (score 1):

Google limits the list of fetch errors to 1000 per day. There is almost nothing you can do about this.

I cannot tell you why you are getting so many 404 errors.

If you can fix the problem, then you will be able to Mark as Fixed these 404s to remove from the list 1000 per day. But I would only do that if you really need to see any additional errors and you do not have another way to assess broken links on your site. Otherwise, I do not recommend tying to Mark as Fixed any 404 error unless you absolutely know that the page does in fact work correctly.

You can use http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/ to find any broken links for your site. It is far more efficient and will give a complete list. Screaming Frog does require a license for more than 500 pages, but it is affordable and an excellent tool! Most people opt for this tool to help keep their site healthy. It can help you identify exactly where these broken links are. You should be able to see a pattern this way and hopefully find the original problem.